# Redirect from old URL to new URL in Apache Tapestry

Tags: tapestry

I am brand new to Tapestry, so apologies if this is extremely easy to achieve, or if I am wrong about his things fit together.

I a trying to redirect from an old URL to a new URL in tapestry.

OldClass.page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE page-specification PUBLIC
  "-//Apache Software Foundation//Tapestry Specification 4.0//EN"
  "http://tapestry.apache.org/dtd/Tapestry_4_0.dtd">
<page-specification class="OldClass">

  <property name="permission" initial-value="XXX" />

</page-specification>
```

OldClass.java

```
// imports...

public abstract class OldClass extends PageBaseClass implements PageBeginRenderListener {

    public void pageBeginRender(PageEvent event) {
        // redirect code...
        throw new PageRedirectException(...);
    } 
}
```

But I get an error saying `Could not find the template page for OldClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right it is a Tapestry 4 app? I believe page renderer phase is too late for redirection.

As the docs [suggest](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/usersguide/events.html) you need to use `PageValidateListener` event:

> When a page is activated (selected to render the reponse). Throw PageRedirectException to activate a different page.